# Spark DDL Schema JSON Struct

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ddl

## Question

I am trying to define a nested .json schema in pyspark, but cannot get the ddl_schema string to work.

Usually in SQL this would be ROW, I have tried STRUCT below but can't get the data type correct this is the error...

```py
ParseException: 
mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'COMMENT', NOT}(line 6, pos 15)

== SQL ==

    driverId INT,
    driverRef STRING,
    number STRING,
    code STRING,
    name STRUCT(forename STRING, surname STRING),
---------------^^^
    dob DATE,
    nationality STRING,
    url STRING
```

## Data Sample

```
            +--------+----------+------+----+--------------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
            |driverId| driverRef|number|code|                name|       dob|nationality|                 url|
            +--------+----------+------+----+--------------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
            |       1|  hamilton|    44| HAM|   {Lewis, Hamilton}|1985-01-07|    British|http://en.wikiped...|
```

## Code Sample

```py
        mnt = "/mnt/dev/root"
        env = "raw"
        path = "formula1/drivers"
        fileFormat = "json"
        
        inPath = f"{mnt}/{env.upper()}/{path}.{fileFormat}"
        
        
        options = {'header': 'True'}
        
        ddl_schema = """
            driverId INT,
            driverRef STRING,
            number STRING,
            code STRING,
            name STRUCT(forename STRING, surname STRING),
            dob DATE,
            nationality STRING,
            url STRING
        """
        
        drivers_df = (spark
                       .read
                       .options(**options)
                       .schema(ddl_schema)
                       .format(fileFormat)
                       .load(inPath)
                     )
```

Comment: Last I checked, you need an actual `Schema` object with StructType, StringType, etc. What documentation are you referring to, that this ddl schema string is valid? And can you show the actual json, not a dataframe representation of it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, that is actually incorrect. SQL schema (DDL-formatted string) is also an option. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html?highlight=ddl%20formatted%20string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for STRUCT.
Here is the right one:

```
name STRUCT<forename:STRING,surname:STRING>
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html
(search for `Complex types` and choose the SQL tab)

| Data type | SQL name |
| --- | --- |
| BooleanType | BOOLEAN |
| ByteType | BYTE, TINYINT |
| ShortType | SHORT, SMALLINT |
| IntegerType | INT, INTEGER |
| LongType | LONG, BIGINT |
| FloatType | FLOAT, REAL |
| DoubleType | DOUBLE |
| DateType | DATE |
| TimestampType | TIMESTAMP |
| StringType | STRING |
| BinaryType | BINARY |
| DecimalType | DECIMAL, DEC, NUMERIC |
| YearMonthIntervalType | INTERVAL YEAR, INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH, INTERVAL MONTH |
| DayTimeIntervalType | INTERVAL DAY, INTERVAL DAY TO HOUR, INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE, INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, INTERVAL HOUR, INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND, INTERVAL MINUTE, INTERVAL MINUTE TO SECOND, INTERVAL SECOND |
| ArrayType | ARRAY<element_type> |
| StructType | STRUCT<field1_name: field1_type, field2_name: field2_type, …> Note: ‘:’ is optional. |
| MapType | MAP<key_type, value_type> |